# i try rowspan in table which is not working

Tags: html, html-table

hey i tried rowspan in a table to get desired result but result i different from what i want i have also include desired result img and code.. please have a look on code..
thanks

[desired result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDO2h.png)

```html
 <table border="1" width="100%" >
        <!--1st row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">B</td>
        </tr>
        <!--2nd row-->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">C</td>
        </tr>
        <!--3rd row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">D</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">E</td>

            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1">F</td>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">G</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">H</td>

        </tr>
        <!--4th row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">I</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">J</td>
            
        </tr>
        <!--5th row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">K</td>
            <td rowspan="2">L</td>
        </tr>
        <!--6th row-->
       <tr>
           <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">M</td>
       </tr>
      
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine a data set where expressing it with that table would make sense. I suspect you'd be better off ditching the table, writing markup with better semantics, and then applying CSS Grid to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a table for you, this will work as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-river-19qh2?file=/index.html

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-73oq {
  border-color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg-addcolspan {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-73oq" colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        sdfsf<br /><br />SDFSF
      </td>
      <td class="tg-73oq" colspan="3">sdfdsf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-73oq" colspan="3">sdfdsfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-73oq">sdsdff</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq">ssdfsfds</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq" rowspan="3">sdfsfsd</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq" rowspan="2">sdfsfsdfs</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq">sdfdsfsdfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-73oq" colspan="2" rowspan="3">sdfsfsdfds</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq">sdfsfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tg-addcolspan">
      <td class="tg-73oq" rowspan="2">dfdfdf</td>
      <td class="tg-73oq" rowspan="2">dsfsdfsd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-73oq">sdfsfs</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case (i.e. cells with hardly any contents) the only things you can do are:

1.) Add more content to the cells. If the amount of contents corresponds to the cell heights (or becomes even higher), they will adjust automatically.

or

2.) If you intend to have as few contents as in your example code, add a height setting to one of the cells that are supposed to span several rows - see snippet below, where the only change to your original code is an added `height: 4em;` for the bottom cell in the first column ("I").

```html
<table border="1" width="100%" >
        <!--1st row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">B</td>
        </tr>
        <!--2nd row-->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">C</td>
        </tr>
        <!--3rd row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">D</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">E</td>

            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1">F</td>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">G</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">H</td>

        </tr>
        <!--4th row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2" style="height: 4em;">I</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">J</td>
            
        </tr>
        <!--5th row-->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">K</td>
            <td rowspan="2">L</td>
        </tr>
        <!--6th row-->
       <tr>
           <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">M</td>
       </tr>
      
    </table>
```