# How can I build the table with rowspan

Tags: html, css

I have to make a table, but I don't know how to build it, I've try a lot, but I can't.
I want to make a table like this -->

[image]

But I can only do this -->

[image]

I want the f cell to merge the two cells down, in the left middle of the b cell and the g cell.
How can I solve ? THANKS !!!

Here is my code:

```css
table, td {
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 25px;
}

td.a{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td.b{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

td.c{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="a" rowspan="3">b</td>
      <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td class="c" rowspan="3">e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="b" rowspan="2">f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="a" rowspan="2">g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Rememeber to don't use table for layout purpose, better use grd in this case

Comment: But if I use table to build it, how can I fix it ?  I'll try grd as well, but since I'm a beginner in HTML, I haven't learned grd yet, however I'll take your opinion as well.

Comment: The comments about not using tables for layout are correct, but if you need to use a table anyway, here is a pvevious answer of mine to a similar question which might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71050345/5641669

Comment: OKay, I've to make it already, and it's more fast and convenience. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `grid` but if you really wan to use `table`, you will need to fix a height to your `tr`, otherwise you wont see any difference:

```css
tr{
  height: 25px;
}
```

And if you really want to that the height fit with your image, you can double height on the fourth row:

```css
tr:nth-child(4){
  height: 50px;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
table, td {
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr{
  height: 25px;
}
tr:nth-child(4){
  height: 50px;
}
td{
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 25px;
}

td.a{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td.b{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

td.c{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Table</title>
    <style>    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table align="center">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td class="a" rowspan="3">b</td>
              <td>c</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>d</td>
              <td class="c" rowspan="3">e</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="b" rowspan="2">f</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="a" rowspan="2">g</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>h</td>
              <td>i</td>
          </tr>
        <tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **CSS-Grid** to specify the rows and columns and then use `grid-row` property on the the item you want to span to other row it will make your task easier. Make sure you have enough rows available in your table to span one row item to other line.

Comment: OKay, I've to make it already, and it's more fast and convenience. Thanks for your comments